# Challenges with sheet presentation with `sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)` and PropertyWrapper

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, presentation

When employing `sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)`, are there specific considerations that we need to take into account? I have a class, `Presenter`, that centrally manages all presentations, and I utilize the `DynamicProperty` of `CustomProperty` to update `UserDefaults` (for simplicity, its code is omitted here). The provided code demonstrates the correct functionality of `sheet(isPresented:onDismiss:content:)`. However, when incorporating `sheet(item:)` within the given structure, the slider fails to move, although the value is updated, and the reset button does not function.

```
@propertyWrapper
private struct CustomProperty: DynamicProperty {
    @State private var value : CGFloat
    
    init(value: CGFloat) {
        self.value = value
    }

    var wrappedValue: CGFloat {
        get { value }
        nonmutating set { value = newValue }
    }
    
   var projectedValue: Binding<CGFloat> {
        .init(get: { wrappedValue }, set: { wrappedValue = $0 })
    }
}


private struct SheetView34: View {
    @Binding var fontSize: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Slider(value: $fontSize, in: 20...40)
            Button("reset") {
                fontSize = 30
            }
        }
    }
}

@Observable
private class Presenter {
    struct Sheet: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let view: AnyView
    }
    var currentSheet: Sheet?
    static let shared = Presenter()
}

struct SwiftUIView34: View {
    @State var show: Bool = false
    @Bindable private var presenter = Presenter.shared
    @CustomProperty(value: 30) private var fontSize
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("fontSize: \(Int(fontSize))").bold()
            Button("show (isPresented:)") {
                show.toggle()
            }
            Button("show (item:)") {
                let sheet = Presenter.Sheet(view: AnyView(SheetView34(fontSize: $fontSize)))
                Presenter.shared.currentSheet = sheet
            }

        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $show) {
           AnyView(SheetView34(fontSize: $fontSize)
            .presentationDetents([.height(200)]))
        }
        .sheet(item: $presenter.currentSheet) { sheet in
            sheet.view
                .presentationDetents([.height(200)])
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SwiftUIView34()
}
```